# How to add a new item to a list pre-filled by linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that pre-filled .Imagine it has 3 item that filled.Now,I want add to list an new item that is null.Befor I use AddRange for a list that is null,but for this case I don't know do,  How to do it by linq ?

```
List<paramodel> Params=_readonlyService.GetAll();
```

I use AddRange but not recognized for this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a null item to a list or that the list itself is null?

Comment: @Zebra what do you mean by *new item that is null* ?

Comment: @user3185569 I want a new list add to params In the other hand I want cocat new list to params list,In  use cocat list but not worked for me .

Comment: @Zebra check my answer below using `Concat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for *NULL* then:

For Single Item:

```
List<paramodel> Params=_readonlyService.GetAll();
if(Params!= null)
    Params.Add(toBeAddedObject);
```

For Multiple Items:

```
List<paramodel> Params=_readonlyService.GetAll();
    if(Params!= null)
        Params.AddRange(secondList);
```

Comment: you will get `System.ArgumentNullException` if the `.GetAll()` returns `null`

Comment: @Zebra `AddRange` or `Concat` ?

Comment: I create new list first and add to params by AddRange.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<PetViewModel> Params = new List<PetViewModel>();

    Params = _readonlyService.GetAll().ToList();
    if (Params.Count() != 0)
    {
        Params.Union(SecondList);
    }
    else
    {
      Params = SecondList;
    }
```